# Choosing good sample from the Universe

Tags: probability, computational-complexity

Let ,  be two disjoint subsets of a universe  such that ||=||=. Suppose we select a random subset ⊆ by independently sampling each element of  with probability ; that means, for each element  of  independently we include  in  with probability . We say that the random subset  is good if the following two conditions hold: ∩=∅ and ∩ has at least one element. Show that for =1/, the probability that  is good is larger than some positive constant.

How would we do this? How to show it has a positive lower bound?

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS:** Since you're looking for a lower bound, you might focus on the worst-case scenarios.

At a minimum, you need:

- **nothing** drawn from set $T$
- **something** -- or, rather, **not nothing** drawn from set $S$

You can find the probabilities of each of these things occurring, and you can multiply them together since they're independent. I claim that the resulting expressions are related to a famous calculus limit, which is how you can get the more difficult of the two bounds.

Can you take it from here?